# SQL Datetime not working with between

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I have a query where i need to get a range of dates, Its an SSRS query so the dates come in as varchars. The thing is when I use between on the date it doesn't return any values that I know are there

```
declare @start datetime,
@end datetime

set @start =convert(datetime,'10/13/2014')
set @end =convert(datetime,'10/13/2014')
SELECT  
      ReleasedDate
FROM tblJobHold
WHERE ReleasedDate between @start and @end
```

same thing with this:

```
declare @start datetime,
@end datetime

set @start =convert(datetime,'10/13/2014')
set @end =convert(datetime,'10/13/2014')
SELECT  
ReleasedDate]
  FROM [tblJobHold]
  WHERE[ReleasedDate] <= @start and [ReleasedDate] >= @end
```

Is there a way to get a datetime to work properly when its been converted to a varchar?

Comment: What type is `ReleasedDate`?

Comment: `WHERE[ReleasedDate] <= @start and [ReleasedDate] >= @end` wouldn't work anyways, try `WHERE[ReleasedDate] >= @start and [ReleasedDate] <= @end`

Comment: Try `set @start =convert(datetime,'10/13/2014 00:00:00')
set @end =convert(datetime,'10/13/2014 23:59:59')`

Comment: do not use between for dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving same date for both start and end times

As you are giving only date, the time component will be midnight , as times are same you don't find any records

```
  set @start =convert(datetime,'10/13/2014')
  set @end =convert(datetime,'10/13/2014')
```

Comment: Yeah, I get that now that you pointed it out. Any way around it?

Comment: @rigamonk, you need to give time also to end date 10/13/2014 23:59:59

Comment: @rigamonk: You can use `[ReleasedDate] >= @start AND [ReleasedDate] < @end` where `@start = '10/13/2014'` and `@end = '10/14/2014'`. That way, you get the entire day 13.

Comment: Setting the time is not an option since I'm just using a date picker in SSRS. Though that works perfect. Figures...

Answer (score 1):

> Its an SSRS query so the dates come in as varchars

If you're passing in parameters you can set the parameter to a date type. Not sure what the issue is there.

> Is there a way to get a datetime to work properly when its been converted to a varchar?

Not the way you want to - when you convert to a `varchar`, ordering (and comparison) use the string values rather than the dates they represent.

If `ReleasedDate` is a `varchar` column just convert it to a `datetime` first:

```
SELECT  
      ReleasedDate
FROM tblJobHold
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,ReleasedDate) between @start and @end
```